# Best practice for allowing user to login with google and facebook on android

Tags: android, facebook, google-account

I am working on building out an api that should allow a user login using either their google account or their facebook account, from android.

I would love some pointers about the best way to go about this.

Should I use the facebook/google auth token in every request?

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/